# Creating Functional Dependencies

Tags: normalization

Ive been trying to normalize a map i have created for a database im making and im having some trouble defining what the FDs would be.

I have a table:

```
User(userID(primary key), Fname, Lname, AccntType, Utype, RegDate, Status, Email, Uname, Pword)
```

It seems as if I would have to put all of those tables in the one FD, though it doesnt seem right to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: All what tables? YOu only describe one.

Comment: They all look functionally dependent on userID to me, at a first glance.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking. So it would okay to have just one large FD with all of those in it?

Comment: FD's really are capturing the **`meaning`** of the data. They are what they are. Messing with them to get some sort of optimization of a particular operation is Denormalization.

Comment: Is "Email" or "Uname" unique?